# failing to get the expected output in hackerrank day2 program

Tags: java, math, casting, percentage

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Arithmetic
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double mealCost = scan.nextDouble(); // original meal price
    double tipPercent = scan.nextDouble(); // tip percentage
    double taxPercent = scan.nextDouble(); // tax percentage
    scan.close();

    // Write your calculation code here.
   tipPercent = mealCost*tipPercent/100.0;
    taxPercent =mealCost*taxPercent/100.0;



  //cast the result of the rounding operation to an int and save it as totalCost 

    double totalCost = mealCost + tipPercent + taxPercent;

    // Print your result
   int total = (int)totalCost; 
    System.out.println("The total meal cost is " +  total + " dollars.");
}
}
```

input:
20.75
10
3
expected output:The total meal cost is 23 dollars.

resulting output:The total meal cost is 26 dollars.

what's wrong with this program?

Comment: Did you debug your program yet? Did you verify that the individual steps produce the correct result? Why do you use the values ``20`` and ``8``?

Comment: you are not using your input arguments, overwriting them instead with hardcoded numbers.....

Comment: Shouldn't your expected result be 33 dollars? Just simple addition of all three gives you 33.75!

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ ok. but even if i used the input arguments it is failing in other test case i,e  for the inputs 10.25  
                                    17  
                                     5  resulting o/p:The total meal cost is 12 dollars.  but expected is:The total meal cost is 13 dollars.

Comment: @vijay_ky with the inputs `10.25 17 5` I am getting the result `The total meal cost is 13 dollars.` What is the exact problem here? Also, if it shouldn't be `13` then tell us how are you actually calculating your expected results!

Comment: @procrastinator it should be 13, but i am getting 12.here is the problem details [link] (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-operators)

Comment: @vijay_ky i am getting 13. Check [here](https://ideone.com/GWJXeG)

Comment: @procrastinator i just updated the code now check and if you would go through the link above you will get know about the problem and what is troubling

Comment: And now with the code above, it gives me `23` dollars [here](https://ideone.com/ypf1Vy). Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You do not use your tip and tax input.

It should be:

```
tipPercent = mealCost*tipPercent/100.0;
taxPercent = mealCost*taxPercent/100.0;
```

Comment: yes i did. even though it is resulting same not expected.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. When I took your code and did my changes on it, it outputted the expected result. Maybe you got something wrong with your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

**finally this code works perfectly**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Arithmetic
{

public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double mealCost = scan.nextDouble(); // original meal price
    double tipPercent = scan.nextDouble(); // tip percentage
    double taxPercent = scan.nextDouble(); // tax percentage
    scan.close();

    // Write your calculation code here.
   tipPercent = mealCost*tipPercent/100.0;
    taxPercent =mealCost*taxPercent/100.0;

    // cast the result of the rounding operation to an int and save it as 
//totalCost 
    double totalCost = mealCost + tipPercent + taxPercent;

    if((tipPercent + 0.5)>=((int)tipPercent + 1))
       {
           totalCost  += 1;
       }
       else
    {
    }
    // Print your result
   int total = (int)totalCost; 
    System.out.println("The total meal cost is " +  total + " dollars.");
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not a general solution. You're just hardcodingly setting the value to `totalCost`.